# Is there a function in shell script equivalent a var_dump(PHP)

Tags: shell-script

I'm doing some examples following [this tutorial](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html) and I was curious to know if there is this kind of function in shell (var_dump PHP) because I [Googled](https://www.google.com/search?q=is%20there%20a%20function%20in%20shell%20script%20equivalent%20a%20var_dump(PHP)&rct=j) and found nothing.

For following these tutorials I'm trying to do something useful and have the following example:

```
pids=$(ps -C pidgin -o pid=)
if [ -z $pids ];
     then
         echo "have pids" $pids
     else
         echo "do not have pids" $pids
fi
```

But I cannot validate the variable 'pids' even with "-n or -z or ! $pids"
always prints the number of pidgin pids even in if or else condition
Running on terminal show this:

```
bash: [: 2480: binary operator expected
do not have pids 2480 20700
```

How can I property make this sentence work for this example?

Comment: I'm not sure where to begin, there is so much wrong here.  First, your title seems to be about things that aren't even in the question.  Second, you point to a tutorial about things that aren't even in the script you posted.  You don't say which OS and shell you are using, so I guessed.  Then the script seems to have a space that doesn't belong there (in the if).  You also need quoting there to make a valid expression.  Could you please edit the text to fix at least some of these, and also what _you_ are expecting (rather than what `[` was expecting), and maybe someone can help.

Comment: To at least make the script run properly, change the first line to `pids="$(ps -C pidgin -o pid=)"` and change the second line to `if [ -z "$pids" ];`.

Comment: You may want to take a look at the [`Debugging Bash scripts` section of the `Bash Guide for Beginners`](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html).

Comment: this work too, and sorry about my English, google translate help me.

Comment: @Lawrence Velázquez your first change (`v="$(...)"` instead of `v=$(...)`) makes  no difference; it's purely cargo-cult.

Comment: @pizdelect No functional difference in this particular case, yes; I expect I didn't know that three years ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should quote it like this:

```
if [ -z "$pids" ]
```

If you ever find yourself using a variable outside of quote marks, you're probably doing it wrong.

Comment: Thanks, this work, now I got the real result work, I  understand how it works like, was my mistake. thanks.